# How to fix credential and token error when using Firebase-Admin SDK Account

Tags: javascript, firebase, sdk, admin

quick question about SDK Admin. I initialized it in my code, but when I call an admin funciton it complains about credentials and tokens, any idea what this could be caused by?

```
var serviceAccount = require('../../../path to the actual json file);
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin
        .credential
        .cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://<name of my database>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

And then I get this error:

```
Error fetching user data: Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Failed to parse access token response: Error: Error while making request: incorrect header check. Error code: Z_DATA_ERROR".
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (error.js:39)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (error.js:85)
    at new FirebaseAppError (error.js:119)
    at firebase-app.js:121
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this? The path to the file is correct.